# Overriding a core admin block not working - to add carriers

Tags: module, blocks, extensions, adminhtml, overrides

I am new to Magento and i'm trying to override Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Shipment/Create/Tracking
in a module to add extra options for carriers in the shipping and tracking section and i cant figure out why this is not working?

Heres my code:

Module xml: app/etc/modules/Essential_Emailtracking.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <Essential_Emailtracking>
   <active>true</active>
   <codePool>local</codePool>
  </Essential_Emailtracking>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Module config.xml: app/code/local/Essential/Emailtracking/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>

  <modules>
   <Essential_Emailtracking>
     <version>0.1.0</version>
   </Essential_Emailtracking>
  </modules>

  <global>
   </blocks>
    <adminhtml>
     <rewrite>
      <sales_order_shipment_create_tracking>Essential_Emailtracking_Block_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Tracking</sales_order_shipment_create_tracking>
     </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
   </blocks>
  </global>
 </config>
```

My Block to override core mage block: app/code/local/Essential/Emailtracking/Block/Sales/Order/Shipment/Create/Tracking.php

```
<?php

class Essential_Emailtracking_Block_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Tracking extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Tracking
{
/**
 * Prepares layout of block
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Giftmessage
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild('add_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
                'label'   => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Add Tracking Number'),
                'class'   => '',
                'onclick' => 'trackingControl.add()'
            ))

    );

}

/**
 * Retrieve shipment model instance
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment
 */
public function getShipment()
{
    return Mage::registry('current_shipment');
}

/**
 * Retrieve
 *
 * @return unknown
 */
public function getCarriers()
{
    $carriers = array();
    $carrierInstances = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers(
        $this->getShipment()->getStoreId()
    );
    $carriers['usps2'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('USPS');
    $carriers['canada_post'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Canada Post');
    $carriers['aus_post'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Australia Post');
    $carriers['custom'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Value');
    foreach ($carrierInstances as $code => $carrier) {
        if ($carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) {
            $carriers[$code] = $carrier->getConfigData('title');
        }
    }
    return $carriers;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you are calling `getCarriers()` method?

Comment: Its being called in the tracking.phtml file here app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/tracking.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your config.xml. Instead of opening `blocks` tag,  you have closed it.  Correct it as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>

  <modules>
   <Essential_Emailtracking>
     <version>0.1.0</version>
   </Essential_Emailtracking>
  </modules>
<global>
       <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
         <rewrite>
          <sales_order_shipment_create_tracking>Essential_Emailtracking_Block_Sales_Order_Shipment_Create_Tracking</sales_order_shipment_create_tracking>
         </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
       </blocks>
      </global>
     </config>
```

Comment: I have made the change and still doesn't seem to want to work?

Comment: did you flush magento cache?

Comment: yeah certainly did

Comment: It just worked fine for me... https://www.dropbox.com/s/soek1eljvnsdnwk/app.zip?dl=0

Comment: I've just tried it out in a clean install of magento with the sample data and i'm still not getting the updated options in the dropdown box under the shipping and tracking information on the shipment page? Am i missing something here? or am i looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Can you show me some screen shots of what you are checking and where?

Comment: I'm checking here in the sales>shipments section
[![Screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpm4t.jpg